# Sort an array from bottom to top and reverse. Get only the 10% of the total array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
"missed_votes_pct" = [4.61, 0.53, 0.18, 0.89, 0.53, 2.3, 4.96, 
0.71, 0.35, 4.26, 0.35, 1.06, 0.89, 1.06, 
0.18, 0.89, 9.54, 0, 3.9, 4.26, 0.35, 1.77, 
0.35, 0.53, 5.67, 0.35, 1.42, 13.65, 2.66, 
0.18, 0.18, 6.38, 0.71, 8.51, 4, 0.35, 0.35,
 5.14, 0, 0.35, 0.53, 0.35, 4.61, 3.01, 4.43,
 2.13, 1.24, 1.7, 2.13, 10.99, 0.53, 2.09, 
0.53, 0.35, 0, 0.53, 0, 0.35, 3.01, 1.77, 
0.89, 0.53, 45.56, 2.48, 0, 14.89, 1.77, 
4.43, 3.19, 0.35, 2.84, 6.21, 3.55, 1.24, 
0.89, 0.71, 0, 0.89, 1.24, 1.6, 6.21, 2.48,
 1.06, 2.13, 0.18, 0.89, 65, 3.19, 0.89, 0, 
0.89, 3.4, 3.55, 1.06, 0, 3.37, 4.96, 1.06, 0.71,
 1.42]

function getTenPerOfMissed(array) {
  var temp = [];
  var len = array.length * 0.1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // console.log(array[i].missed_votes_pct);

    if (i < len) {
      temp.push(array[i]);
    } else if (array[i].missed_votes_pct == array[i - 1].missed_votes_pct) { //find the 10% of the lowest values and keep also values that                                                                               repeated
      temp.push(array[i]);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(temp);
}


function bottomTenPercent() {
  members.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.missed_votes_pct - b.missed_votes_pct; //sort our array from lower to higher and call getTenPerOfMissed(members)
    //to keep the 10% of the lowest values
  });
  // console.log("Lowest" , members)
  getTenPerOfMissed(members)
}


function TopTenPercent() {
  members.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.missed_votes_pct - a.missed_votes_pct;
  });

  getTenPerOfMissed(members);
}


bottomTenPercent();
TopTenPercent();
```

I have create these three functions to sort an array from higher to lower and reverse. Also i need to keep only the 10% percent  of the numbers and i have to keep the number that they are repeated. 
 When I print my temp array with the sorted numbers are unable to work together both of the sorted functions. If i call only one of them work perfect.
 Also i need to have access in the temp[] because i want to print the numbers in a table. What process i have to follow because i can't realize at all the process and when i try to set the temp[] as an global variable my functions doesn't work well 
Any ideas what i am doing wrong? because i have stuck on this task for two days. I am new in javascript so forgive me if my the question is dumb

Comment: Hi there, to properly illustrate your question can you give us examples of the input, and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: What do you mean by 10% ? If the input is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` whats the expected output?

Comment: can you share the array?

Comment: Thank you very much. The output should be array.length * 0.1 and  if there are repeated number should me included it as well.

Comment: What should the output from those numbers be.  Make it clear so you get a good answer.

Comment: Again: whats your expected output? Should duplicates be removed or counted at all? Is it 10% of the total value or 10% of the values?

Comment: I edited my code  sorry if i  don't explain something very well..

Comment: If the array has length 100 I need to keep the first 10 lower and higher values but if the last value repeated i need to keep them as well....

Comment: Write out the values you need for both of your outputs (bottomTenPercent();
TopTenPercent();) in the question.  Example: *bottomTenPercent should output* `[0.3, 0.4, 0.4]`

Comment: [0.4 , 0.5 , 0.6 , 0.7, 0.4 0.10, 0.9, 0.9 , 0.6, 0.8] .  bottomTePer:0.4 , 0.4  TopTenPercent: 0.10

Comment: Guys solved i don't understand how but it works properly! :) :) Really sorry if i don't explain it well. Now an other question i want to have access in temp array because i want to print the data in an html table. How i can any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to open up that temp array is to return it from your getTenPerOfMissed function.  Then, whatever function called it has access to the modified array.

```
function getTenPerOfMissed(array) {
  var temp = [];
  var len = array.length * 0.1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //  console.log(array[i].missed_votes_pct);

    if (i < len) {
      temp.push(array[i]);
    } else if (array[i].missed_votes_pct == array[i - 1].missed_votes_pct) { //find the 10% of the lowest values and keep also values that                                                                               repeated
      temp.push(array[i]);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

  var topten = getTenPerOfMissed(array);
  // topten is the "temp" array from getTenPerOfMissed

  // sort array differently
  array.sort(...);
  var bottomten = getTenPerOfMissed(array);
```

Comment: So now you have define each array in a new variable?

Comment: Yeah, and then you work with the topten and bottomten variables, writing them out to your display or whatever you're going to do with them.

Comment: Really thanks, it's so easy, but my mind did not work ον this way I need a lot of practice ....

Answer (score 1):

When you are sorting , you dont need this  `a.missed_votes_pct - b.missed_votes_pct`, this expect `missed_votes_pct` to be an key inside an object.In that case the array will look like this

```
[{missed_votes_pct:someVal},{missed_votes_pct:someVal}]
```

Only sorting `missed_votes_pct` which is just an array will be fine. You can either use `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` to get the round digit because 10% array length can also give a floating number.

You can use `splice` to create a sub array.

Technically you dont need two function to get top and bottom 10%.You can sort in ascending order & use `array.splice(start,howmany)` to get top 10 & `array.splice(-10)` to get last 10 which highest

```js
let missed_votes_pct = [4.61, 0.53, 0.18, 0.89, 0.53, 2.3, 4.96,
  0.71, 0.35, 4.26, 0.35, 1.06, 0.89, 1.06,
  0.18, 0.89, 9.54, 0, 3.9, 4.26, 0.35, 1.77,
  0.35, 0.53, 5.67, 0.35, 1.42, 13.65, 2.66,
  0.18, 0.18, 6.38, 0.71, 8.51, 4, 0.35, 0.35,
  5.14, 0, 0.35, 0.53, 0.35, 4.61, 3.01, 4.43,
  2.13, 1.24, 1.7, 2.13, 10.99, 0.53, 2.09,
  0.53, 0.35, 0, 0.53, 0, 0.35, 3.01, 1.77,
  0.89, 0.53, 45.56, 2.48, 0, 14.89, 1.77,
  4.43, 3.19, 0.35, 2.84, 6.21, 3.55, 1.24,
  0.89, 0.71, 0, 0.89, 1.24, 1.6, 6.21, 2.48,
  1.06, 2.13, 0.18, 0.89, 65, 3.19, 0.89, 0,
  0.89, 3.4, 3.55, 1.06, 0, 3.37, 4.96, 1.06, 0.71,
  1.42
];


function getTenPerOfMissed(array) {
  var temp = [];
  var len = Math.ceil(array.length * 0.1);
  return array.splice(0, 10);

}


function bottomTenPercent(members) {
  let memsortedMems = members.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  return getTenPerOfMissed(memsortedMems)
}


function TopTenPercent(members) {
  let memsortedMems = members.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });
  return getTenPerOfMissed(memsortedMems);
}


console.log(bottomTenPercent(missed_votes_pct));
console.log(TopTenPercent(missed_votes_pct));
```